# OpenID and Google

Tags: google-api, openid, google-openid

I have just read that [Google has deprecated OpenID 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID). In the [migration information](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#oauth2login), they say to "Change endpoint: You must replace the **userinfo** endpoint with the **people.get** endpoint by using the following HTTP request path:   https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me "

But, I haven't found the "userinfo" endpoint anywhere in my program. I connect to OpenID using LightOpenID, saying:

```
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
```

So, what exactly should I replace with "people.get"?

Comment: I think we have plenty of time to migrate: _[Support for the OpenID 2.0 identifier mapping described above will remain in effect until January 1, 2017](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect)_

Answer (score 1):

The document you are reading applies if you were migrating from "OAuth 2.0 login". Since you are migrating from "OpenID 2.0" instead, you need to read

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect